# Docker volume mount windows container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am getting the following error while trying to mount a volume in windows docker container.

```
===============
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 1234567ebcdh encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)
================
```

I have mentioned almost all the possible combinations of `c:/app` in docker file but still getting error while starting the container itself without `-v` option.

```
-----------
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]
WORKDIR /application
COPY . .
VOLUME C:/application
CMD cmd
-----------
```

- OS: Windows 10
- Docker: Docker for windows 2.0.0

If you have any idea what went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be followed with [`docker/for-win` issue 676](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/676) which [includes](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/676):

> I was also having this exact issue:
>
> ```
> docker: Error response from daemon: container XYZ encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106).
> ```
>
> I found 2 solutions for my case:
>
> I was able to successfully build and run the image by reducing the number of layers in the history. (For me this number happened to be a max of 37 layers in history.) (If your dockerfile is based on a 2nd dockerfile, you may need to reduce the number of steps in the 2nd dockerfile.)
>
> - How to debug: I was able to debug this by cutting the number of steps in half until the image ran, then re-adding steps until I discovered how many steps the history could have before breaking the image.
> - I was able to successfully build and run the image without reducing the number of layers by making sure that the root image was a certain version of windowsservercore:1709 (specifically, the 10.0.16299.904_en-us version of 1709, which does not appear to be pull-able anymore; however, it might also work with the latest version of windowsservercore:1709, I haven't tried).
>     I didn't debug this, I discovered this by blind luck.

Note: the same issue reports that [mounting can be problematic](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/676#issuecomment-337110682).

Comment: yeah VonC, I have already reduced the number of layers and the dockerfile consist of only basic commands. The build was successful and image is created  but when I try to start the container with same image it will fail with above error.

Comment: I tried with windowsservercore:1709 image aswell but getting the same error while trying to start the container.

Comment: @jibin087 what is your host Windows version (typing `winver` in a cmd)?

Comment: My OS Version is Windows 10, version 1709

Comment: @jibin087 That is what I thought. It might be possible that a more recent host kernel (1803/1809) makes that issue disappear.

Comment: Any alternative solution that we can apply here to get rid of this error? making changes on OS is not possible.

Comment: Basically I am trying to run nunit3-console.exe for running test cases. Is there any alternate image which we can use for running this. I tried with different images like nano. .net run time images etc but its not executing the exe file.

Comment: @jibin087 is it not executing the exe file with the same error message?

Comment: I am getting this error while trying to start the container itself and its not starting. this is not related to exe file execution. If I comment out VOLUME in docker file then container will start with new image.

Comment: @jibin087 Yes: my comment was about the host (Windows 1709) starting your container: maybe a Windows 10 1803 or 1810 would support mounting the volume.